# Add a field from a One-To-Many relationship in sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Let's say you have an entity **User**. And a **User** entity can have more **Post** entities attached to it. So there is a one-to-many relationship between User and Post.

Is it possible in Sonata in admin class for editing the User, to also edit a field from a Post(for example **title**)? If yes, can you give me some guidelines?

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and SonataAdminBundle 2.3.0.

Comment: Did you have a solution yet?

Comment: Apparently is not possible to do that with Sonata yet

Comment: I have found a kind of solution actually, but decided to do it another way.